# Find a html control via it's attribute and value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find an `<a>` tag via its attribute and the attribute value via javascript... but it doesn't work...

```
<a class="btn-u btn-u-split-red tooltips CancelOredr" data-guid="1351e01d-8e89-4adc-b3f2-10c0c8ccaa5b" href="/User/UserProfile/Index/1351e01d-8e89-4adc-b3f2-10c0c8ccaa5b" title="" data-placement="bottom" "></a>

<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.CancelOredr', function (e) {
        var OrderID = "1351e01d-8e89-4adc-b3f2-10c0c8ccaa5b";
        var trEl = $('[data_guid=' + OrderID + ']');
        trEl.css("background", "#F5F5AF");
        trEl.delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You are using `_` instead of `-` .

Comment: `data_guid != data-guid` - `var trEl = $('[data-guid=' + OrderID + ']');`

Comment: The browser will follow the link before your button/link has time to fade out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an underscore in your JS that is a hyphen in your html:

`var trEl = $('[data_guid='+OrderID +']');`

should be:

`var trEl = $('[data-guid='+OrderID +']');`

Comment: :)) Thanks :)) :)) :))